# Ruby on Rails, How would I update a variable passed to a view with a helper form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, view, controller

controller creates a @variable

```
def main
 @variable = "People are awesome!"
end
```

The view presents the @variable as the header

```
<h1><%= @variable %></h1>
<%= form_for(@variable) do |f| %>
 <%= f.text_field :variable%>
 <%= f.submit "Change Header"%>
<%end%>
```

Here's what my routes.rb looks like

```
#testArea
 get 'test' => 'testscripts#main'
 post 'test' => 'testscripts#main'
```

Would I be able to update the header without passing the submission to a whole different view?

Thank you in advance. I really appreciate your time.

Comment: I didn't get what you are looking for ..... But yes without any kind of event, you can't do that.

Comment: What's the question here?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following

```
def main
@variable = Variable.new
end
```